# How Test Google Play Billing

Tags: java, android, google-play, billing, android-billing

I've put an application on Google Play for $5. How do I know if a user using this app has bought it? I am a beginner please help me !

I need to use such a way in my application:

```
if (appBought) {

   //SOME_WORK_1

} else {

   //SOME_WORK_2

}
```

Comment: see this video you will get idea how to test in app https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ip5C4hp9vW0

Comment: I need code to use in my application that do one user using this app has bought it or no.

Comment: google give a success response and then you have to store that into a server or in local db and define the function of your appBought value